# Django displaying error messages from two separated methods?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model defined as below:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Although both defined as uniqe, django admin allows me to add categories like "python", "Python", "PYTHON". I know this is the default behavior.

To prevent this i have created a `clean()` method in Category models as follows:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    slug = slugify(self.name.lower())
    r = Category.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    print("size")
    print(r.count())
    if r:
        raise ValidationError("Category with this name already exists. Try again with a new name.")
    self.slug = slug
    super(Category, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works for most of the cases. But lets say database already has `Python` category and if i try to add `Python` again, it will show me two errors one from `clean()` method and one from `validate_unique()` method. Here is how it looks.

[image]

I want to display only one message is there a way to prevent it. Is there any way to override this behavior or something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative and short solution: You can override `save` method to lowercase `name` before saving and get rid of custom `clean` method.

Comment: But i want to preserve casing. Lets say user entered "Introduction to Computer Science", and it get stored as "introduction to computer. science". Then while outputting i have to write custom filters to these too. ?? Isn't

Comment: @gitblame is there any way do without using css specific solution as provided by karthikr.

Comment: I have posted an answer. The idea is to associate error with field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

> To assign exceptions to a specific field, instantiate the ValidationError with a dictionary, where the keys are the field names.

```
if r:
    raise ValidationError({'name': ["Category with this name already exists.",]})
```

Comment: Thanks @gitblame. So is there any way to access `validate_unique()` 's error message. Just curious ?

Comment: I think `clean` is called before `validate_unique`. So this error is raised even before uniqueness is checked by `validate_unique`. This can be any custom error.